Как решить проблему с import в vs code
У меня есть приложение на дарте. И возникла такая проблема, что в файле main и authorization не хочется подключаться основная страница приложения home.dart. Vs code говорит что этот файл никак не используется, но мне нужно чтобы после окна авторизации - перекидывало на основную страницу home.dart



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.



Пару слов, что такое импорт: это подключение модуля для использования.
В приведенном коде использования home нет, поэтому VSC предлагает его удалить. Это нормально и не ошибка.


Для переходов между экранами/страницами приложения флаттер предлагает механизмы навигации. Как только появится использование чего-то вроде Navigator.of(context).push(Home); - VSC перестанет ругаться на импорт, тк появится использование класса Home из соответствующего файла.


